# Blazor Authentication with Azure AD - Retrieving User Roles

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor

I've successfully setup a Blazor application to authenticate with the Azure tenant where I work.  The authentication works beautifully.  I have the App Registration setup in Azure with appRoles defined in the manifest.  I've add a few users to the application with those roles assigned however I'm not getting any Role claims back on the user context after it authenticates.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));


        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

        });
```

Manifest:

```
"appRoles": [
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Coming soon.",
        "displayName": "Viewer",
        "id": "{guid goes here}",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "Viewer"
    },
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Coming soon.",
        "displayName": "Manager",
        "id": "{guid goes here}",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "Manager"
    }
],
```

I'm trying to retrieve those roles with the claims after authentication, but no roles are coming through.  This is obviously making IsInRole not work and for the life of me I can't find any samples of code to achieve this.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: Which blazor do u use, server-side ou wasm ?

Comment: I use server side

Comment: I added my startup code to the original post.

Comment: Can you post the code and the context where you try to read user's roles. Is it in component, in a webapi method ?

Comment: You can make a separate call to the Microsoft Graph to get this information (as a separate call)

Comment: @aguafrommars - I don't have that code yet.  I'm trying to figure that part out.

Comment: @MichaelWashington - I'm having trouble finding decent documentation on how to do that from Blazor.  I have the Graph nuget but can't figure out the calls.

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure what I did, but now it is coming through.  Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: This may help: Blazor Microsoft Graph Calendar Example With Active Directory Authentication http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4358/Blazor-Microsoft-Graph-Calendar-Example-With-Active-Directory-Authentication.aspx

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the user has been assigned application roles, it should be returned in the id token. You can decode the id token by using `https://jwt.io/`.

[image]

I didn't find a blazor sample, but you can refer to this [aspnetcore sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles).